# php opencart 2.1.0.1 mysql query error: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource object given in

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am facing problem in mysql can any one help me to solve this. 
Question : mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource object given in (opencart 2.1.0.1)

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Do two things, Edit your post and update you code in post, and make a echo of `$query` to see the query and run it in the mysql -> phpmyadmin, if it is works fine then good else give us the error message.

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_fields() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart-2.1.0.1\upload\admin\controller\app\feedback.php on line 523

Comment: i said to echo the query and place it in the phpmyadmin. If you are facing problem with echoing the query then use `die()` before the `$sql = mysql_query($query);`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = mysql_query($query)' at line 1

Comment: that means you query is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

public function export(){

```
    $output = "";

    $table = "app_feedback"; // Enter Your Table Name 


  $query = "SELECT ap.*,sr.name as ShowRoomName,CONCAT_WS(' ', sr.address1, sr.address2,sa.showroom_area_name,sc.showroom_city_name,ss.showroom_state_name,'-',sr.pincode) AS ShowroomAddress FROM ".DB_PREFIX."app_feedback ap LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "showroom sr ON (ap.showroom = sr.showroom_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "showroom_area sa ON (sr.showroom_area_id = sa.showroom_area_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "showroom_city sc ON (sr.showroom_city_id = sc.showroom_city_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "showroom_state ss ON (sr.showroom_state_id = ss.showroom_state_id)";

    if(!empty($this->request->get['date_from'])&&!empty($this->request->get['date_to'])){

        $date_from = $this->request->get['date_from'];

        $date_to = $this->request->get['date_to'];

        $time_from = $this->request->get['time_from'];

        if(empty($time_from)){

           $time_from = '00:00';

        }

        $time_to = $this->request->get['time_to'];

        if(empty($time_to)){

           $time_to = '23:59';

        }

//      $query .=" WHERE DATE(date)>= '".$date_from."' AND DATE(date)<='".$date_to."'";

        $query .=" WHERE date BETWEEN '".$date_from. ' '.$time_from.":00' AND '".$date_to.' '.$time_to.":00'";

    }

    $sql = mysql_query($query);

    $columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

    // Get The Field Name

    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {

    $heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);

    if($heading!='showroom')

    {

      $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';

    }

//  $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';

    }
    $output .="\r\n";
    // Get Records from the table
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {

//  $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';

    if($i!=16){

        $values=str_replace('amp;', "", $row["$i"]);

        $output .='"'.$values.'",'; 

    }

    }

    $output .="\r\n";

    }

    // Download the file



    $filename = "feedback.csv";

    header('Content-type: application/csv');

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

    echo $output;

}
```